# C# Regular Expression to split string and return either of the substrings

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string I need to split using a Regex. I could use the split methods in .NET but the string to return could be the first or second substrings.  This regex will become a configurable setting in an application.

A typical string would be 9234567X123456-789

I've create the following regex

```
     [-09]([^X]*)X
```

to return the first substring. However, I lose the first digit, 234567 is returned.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: what data so you want..string separated by X or is it something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want the string to start with either `-`, `0` or `9`. If this is true the regex you need (and using regexes here is overkill unless you want to also perform a sort of validation) is

```
([-09]\d*)X
```

OR

```
([-09][^X]*)X
```

if you are allowing any kind of character (not only digits) in the part before the `X`

**EDIT**:

Might have understood what you are looking for reading your sample string:

```
9234567X123456-789
```

You need either the first or the second group and every group can have digits or hypen (`-`). You solve this by creating two groups:

```
([\d\-]+)X([\d\-]+)
```

then you can check Jon Skeet's answer to get the data. You could either use

```
match.Groups[1]); //to get 9234567
```

or

```
match.Groups[2]); //to get 123456-789
```

Comment: I was planning on performing some validation on the string as you guessed. The string must also start with a -, 0 or 9. I should have mentioned that in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you lose the first digit because it's being taken by the `[-09]` part. It's not clear why you've got that at all. I suspect you just want:

```
([^X]*)X
```

In other words, "capture everything before the first X, and check that there really is an X."

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("([^X]*)X");
        string input = "9234567X123456-789";
        Match match = regex.Match(input);
        // TODO: Check for success
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]); // 9234567
    }
}
```